# ODE envolving current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, resonance

I have to do this exercise:

> 9. The current $I(t)$ at time $t$ flowing in an electric circuit obeys the differential equation
>
> $$I''(t) + RI'(t) + I(t) = \sin \omega t$$
>
> where $R$ and $\omega$ are positive constants. The solution can be expressed in the form $I(t) = F(t) + A\sin(\omega t + a)$, where $F(t)\to 0$ as $t\to +\infty$, and $A$ and $\alpha$ are constants depending on $R$ and $\omega$, with $A > 0$. If there is a value of $\omega$ which makes $A$ as large as possible, then $\omega/(2\pi)$ is called a *resonance frequency* of the circuit.
>
> (a) Find all resonance frequencies when $R = 1$.
>   (b) Find those values of $R$ for which the circuit will have a resonance frequency.

I have a doubt about the first item. To find all resonance when $R=1$, I found the particular solution $I_{p}(t)=A\sin(\omega t)+B\cos(\omega t)$.

I got the first and second derivates
$$I_{p}'=A\omega\cos(\omega t)-B\omega\sin(\omega t)$$
$$I_{p}''=-A\omega^{2}\sin(\omega t)-B\omega^{2}\cos(\omega t)$$
then, when I substitute in the equation
$$I''(t)+I'(t)+I(t)=\sin(\omega t)$$
I got the system on $(A,B)$:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-A\omega^{2}-B\omega+A=1 \\
-B\omega^{2}+A\omega+B=0
\end{array}\right.$$
so
$$A=\frac{(1-\omega^{2})}{(1-\omega^{2})^{2}+\omega^{2}}$$
I calculated $A$ because it follows $\sin(\omega t)$ and with this I can find all resonance frequencies.

Well, to find them, I gotta find the values of $\omega$ which makes $A$ as large as possible. To $A\to+\infty$, so, its denominator must goes to 0:
$$(1-\omega^{2})^{2}+\omega^{2}\to0$$
But that's not possible.

The answer is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{2}}$. Comparing with the exercise, I know that $\omega=1/\sqrt{2}$.

If the denominator was $(1-\omega^{2})^{2}-\omega^{2}$, I got the result, but I don't know what's wrong here.

**EDIT:** I found after
$$I_{p}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\omega^{2})^{2}+\omega^{2}}}\sin(\omega t-\alpha)$$
where $\alpha=\arctan(\omega/(1-\omega^{2})$. So,
$$A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\omega^{2})^{2}+\omega^{2}}}$$
and it's large just if its denominator is small... but how?!

Comment: How do you normally find the [maximum or minimum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima) of a function?

Comment: This was cross-posted to Math: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861661/ode-particular-solution-physics